# how to write a function to find Zero value count and % of zero for all the columns and export into excel in python

Tags: python, function

I have one data set which has 780 columns and 87529 rows it contains lots of zero values.
I am using the below code, but I am getting a 780*2 line as result, which is really difficult to read and understand,so i wanted to export this result into excel,can anyone help me to construct the code.

```
for column_name in df.columns:
   column = df[column_name]
   count = (column == 0).sum()
   percent_zero = (column ==0 ).sum()/87529*100
   print('Count of zeros in column ', column_name, ' is : ', count)
```

Comment: Where have indents gone? Paste your code precisely.

Comment: sorry,i have put the indentation ,please check it

Comment: What is your desirable shape of the output?

Comment: 1.column name  2.Number_of_zero  3.%_of_zero result should be extract in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. (You have to use your own `df`)

```py
import pandas as pd

# Use your own dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'col1': 0, 'col2': 0},
    {'col1': 1, 'col2': 0},
    {'col1': 1, 'col2': 1},
    ])

temp = 'Count of zeros in column "{col}" is : {n_zeros} (Percentage: {percent_zero:.1f}%)'
n_rows = len(df)
seeds = []

for col, ser in df.iteritems():
    n_zeros = (ser == 0).sum() 
    percent_zero = n_zeros / n_rows * 100
    print(temp.format(col=col, n_zeros=n_zeros, percent_zero=percent_zero))
    seeds.append({'column_name': col, 'number_of_zero': n_zeros, 'percent_of_zero': percent_zero})

df_out = pd.DataFrame(seeds)
df_out.to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False)
```

If you got an error related to export, try this command:

```sh
pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: I updated my code from the initial version. Check the output excel file.